# Grouping radio buttons without name attribute

Tags: c#, html, .net, razor, model-view-controller

I've got a form similar to the below, the name attributes have been set with MVC model binding in mind.

At the moment I'm only able to select one radio between the two forms. I want to select a radio button for each form,  i.e. one radio button selected per form at any given time. I can't find a way to do this whilst keeping my name attribute naming convention.

Any ideas, thanks.

```
<div class="form-group-1">
       <input type="radio" name="Students[0].Answer1" value=""><br>
       <input type="radio" name="Students[0].Answer2" value=""><br>
</div>

<div class="form-group-2">
      <input type="radio" name="Students[1].Answer1" value=""><br>
      <input type="radio" name="Students[1].Answer2" value=""><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I stand to be corrected-- but I believe you're only able to choose one thing between the two due to them being in the same `name`. While they're different parts of it, they're still all `Students`.

Comment: @Symon Thanks for  your response, hopefully there is a way around it  - otherwise it'll be unfortunate!

Comment: I'm not versed enough in HTML to be able to provide a proper answer-- Hopefully someone is able to come along and correct me/have an answer for you!